# How to get the 'Guardin' Gnome' achievement in Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: achievements, left-4-dead-2

How can I get the *Guardin' Gnome* achievement in *Left 4 Dead 2* on Steam?

The text of the achievement is the following:

> Rescue Gnome Chompski from the Carnival.

So I suppose it has to be done in the *Dark Carnival* campaign, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an eHow article ([now archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20100129180531/http://www.ehow.com/how_5707250_unlock-achievement-left-dead-2.html)) detailing how to unlock the achievement, but the basic steps are as follows:

In stage 2 of the Dark Carnival, score 750 points on the shooting game before time runs out. Upon winning, you get Gnome Chompski.

Your party then has to carry Gnome Chompski into the escape vehicle at the end of the campaign. You can drop the Gnome as much as you want, and any player can pick the Gnome up, but you must carry him to the end.

Comment: I got it yesterday, a tough one!

Comment: @Juan - If you find it tough, think that there is a similar achievement for Half-Life: Episode 2, where you have to carry a gnome during **all the single player adventure**.

Comment: On a side note, as it wasn't mentioned on the eHow article, you do not need to try to get the 750 points solo. Your friends can help you in the shooting gallery as well and you will still get him as a reward.

Comment: It seems tough indeed, but if I can put it down I think I can do it! Thanks for the info.

Comment: on easy mode, it's pretty easy. just watch out for boomers - if the gnome is on the ground and one explodes nearby, the gnome will go flying. There was a fun mutation based on guarding the gnome where you could take him through any campaign. I hope they bring that back sometime.

Answer (score 1):

One little tip:

When you are in the safe room at the end of each map, you need to be holding the Gnome for the map to really finish. Closing the door is not sufficient.
Might not be obvious for some (like me :))